# Remove Duplicate Namespaces from XML in Java

Tags: java, xml, dom, jdom, jdom-2

I have the following soap response as a sample:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:urn="urn:mycompany:Service:2" xmlns:urn1="urn:mycompany:Customer:2">
  <soapenv:Header />
  <soapenv:Body>
    <urn:GetResponse>
      <urn:StatusCode>002</urn:StatusCode>
      <urn:StatusMessage>Pass</urn:StatusMessage>
      <urn:CustomerAffiliations>
        <urn:CustomerAffiliation>
          <urn:CustomerID>II39642</urn:CustomerID>
          <urn:CustomerContactDetails>
            <ns3:Channel xmlns:ns3="urn:mycompany:Customer:2">Business Phone</ns3:Channel>
            <ns3:Value xmlns:ns3="urn:mycompany:Customer:2">5553647</ns3:Value>
          </urn:CustomerContactDetails>
        </urn:CustomerAffiliation>
      </urn:CustomerAffiliations>
    </urn:GetResponse>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

`urn:mycompany:Customer:2` has been included as `urn1` in `soapenv:Envelope` but it is duplicated in `ns3:Channel` and `ns3:Value`.

The requirement is to clean the xml content so the correct namespaces declared in `soapenv:Envelope` is used in the child elements.

Is there a way in Java to clean/normalize this xml content and use proper namespace usage and duplication removal?

Comment: Related: https://github.com/hunterhacker/jdom/issues/163

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code will replace "duplicated" namespaces with their inherited versions for elements only (Attributes could have their own namespaces too)....

Note that this has some horrible time-complexity, so for larger XML documents this could degenerate quite badly.... so don't use this on deeply nested, or documents larger than a few hundred elements... at some point the time complexity will bite you.

On the other hand, for small packets like your SOAP example, it will be more than enough...

```
private static final Namespace findFirst(List<Namespace> namespaces, String uri) {
    for (Namespace ns : namespaces) {
        if (ns.getURI().equals(uri)) {
            return ns;
        }
    }
    return null;
}


public static final void dedupElementNamespaces(Element node) {
    List<Namespace> created = node.getNamespacesIntroduced();
    if (!created.isEmpty()) {
        // check anything new against other stuff...
        List<Namespace> inherited = node.getNamespacesInherited();
        // check out element against previous declarations....
        if (node.getNamespace().getPrefix() != "") {
            // never swap defaulted namespaces to anything with a prefix.
            Namespace ens = node.getNamespace();
            Namespace use = findFirst(inherited, node.getNamespaceURI());
            if (use != null && use != ens) {
                node.setNamespace(use);
            }
        }           

    }
    for (Element e : node.getChildren()) {
        dedupElementNamespaces(e);
    }
}
```

You can call that with:

```
dedupElementNamespaces(doc.getRootElement());
```

The methods `node.getNamespacesIntroduced()` and `node.getNamespacesInherited()` compute lists dynamically by scanning up the XML hierarchy... so their performance depends on the depth of nesting. See https://github.com/hunterhacker/jdom/blob/master/core/src/java/org/jdom2/Element.java#L1753

Comment: Any idea on the implementation of `findFirst` method? Whats the method doing?

Comment: Hmmm... not sure why I missed copying that code the first time around. It's not complicated, but I have added it here.